# Merge duplicate datatable records into XML document

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, datatable, hierarchy

I have a datatable with category/subcategory records in the format below:

```
hierarchy  id1   cat1   id2    cat2         id3    cat3
        4  3105  Mens   3195    Shorts      3130    Shorts
        4  3105  Mens   3195    Shorts      3196    Swim Shorts
        4  3105  Mens   3177    Knitwear    3118    Jumpers
        4  3105  Mens   3177    Knitwear    3178    Cardigans
        4  3105  Mens   3177    Knitwear    3814    V-Neck Knitwear
```

I'm trying to convert it to xml in a format like this:

```
<CATEGORY  NAME="mens">
        <CATEGORIES NAME="Shorts" />
            <CATEGORIES NAME="Shorts" />
            <CATEGORIES NAME="SwimShorts" />
        <CATEGORIES NAME="Knitwear" />
           <CATEGORIES NAME="Jumpers" />
           <CATEGORIES NAME="Cardigans" />
           <CATEGORIES NAME="V-Neck Knitwear" />
```

But the best I can get is this:

```
 <CATEGORY  NAME="Mens">
        <CATEGORIES NAME="Knits" />
        <CATEGORIES NAME="Crew Neck Knitwear" />
 </CATEGORY>
 <CATEGORY NAME="Mens">
        <CATEGORIES NAME="Knits" />
        <CATEGORIES NAME="Cardigans" />
```

As you can see there are duplicates which I don't want.  I know I need to merge or de-duplicate somehow.

I'm returning the data as `AsEnumerable()` and then doing a foreach and creating an XElement for the top-level category and child XElements for the the subcategories:

```
var e = new XElement("CATEGORY", new XAttribute("ID", item["did1"]), new XAttribute("NAME", item["name1"]),
                        item["did2"].ToString() != "" ? new XElement("CATEGORIES", new XAttribute("ID", item["did2"]), new XAttribute("NAME", item["name2"])) : null,
                        item["did3"].ToString() != "" ? new XElement("CATEGORIES", new XAttribute("ID", item["did3"]), new XAttribute("NAME", item["name3"])) : null,
                        item["did4"].ToString() != "" ? new XElement("CATEGORIES", new XAttribute("ID", item["did4"]), new XAttribute("NAME", item["name4"])) : null
                    );
```

I'm not fussy about what technique I used to product the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this

```
var X = from item in Data
        group item by item.cat1 into g
        select new XElement(
            "CATEGORY",
            new XAttribute("NAME", g.Key),
            from it in g
            group it by it.cat2 into k
            select new XElement("CATEGORIES2", new XAttribute("NAME", k.Key),
                from i in k.Select(x=>x.cat3).Distinct()
                select new XElement("CATEGORIES3", new XAttribute("NAME",i))
                )
        );
```